# UIView is not positioned properly with autolayout enabled storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a view controller, which view (.view property), I am accessing and changing it's frame to show that view using a third party library (named, KLCPopup). This is good.

But the problem is, if I am adding a UIButton inside the storyboard and it always came up at top-center position. So I removed it from the storyboard and tried adding it programmatically, but it still not came up at proper position.

```
_btnFavourite = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_btnFavourite.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[_btnFavourite setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite-not-sel"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_btnFavourite setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite-sel"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
_btnFavourite.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - (lmargin * 2.0f))/2.0f, (self.view.frame.size.height - (tmargin * 2.0f))/2.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
[_btnFavourite setBackgroundColor:UIColor.redColor];
[self.view addSubview:_btnFavourite];
```

I am trying to set the button frame at where I want. But it's always added to a different place.

Comment: where this code is called? It shouldn't be always in different places.

Comment: @mkeremkeskin, I am adding this code in viewDidLoad method. Also, tried with awakeFromNib method.

Comment: So you are adding a button to your ViewController's view in viewDidLoad? If this is the case the button should always be in the same place. The information you are giving is not enough to provide an answer.

Comment: @mkeremkeskin, what you need to know? I can answer them in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Do not *ever* modify frames when you're using autolayout. Your .view.frame should therefore not be modified.

Also, when adding a UIButton (or any visual element) you should not set its frame programatically but rather add new constraints programatically. That way you let iOS handle everything and it will also resize on different phones/orientations all by itself ! (which a .frame wouldn't handle)

Now about your problem, I can't really tell you what exactly you should add as constraints because I don't know where you want your button to be. But learning as much as you can about `NSLayoutConstraint` and reading tutorials is what I strongly advice for you. Its not lost knowledge, and it'll come in handy many many many times.

If you add more info about your current view (screenshots, what you want, what you have, etc.) and the button (where it should be), i'll tell you what constraints to add. It would be a good exercise if you tried yourself for an hour or something and came back with either a solution (that I would gladly add here) or your best result and I'll guide you from there. You'll learn more if I don't flat out give you the answer.

Comment: Hi Zil, thank you for you tip. Now there's I don't have enough time to learn it, I am looking for alternative. Can I create a UIView programmatically (only with frames) and add a button over it and could show it? It will work in autolayout environment?

Comment: Yes you could and it would "work". But it'll be a nightmare in terms of different phone sizes and orientatinons

Answer (score 0):

First, dont modify frames of any view (can create, can add, just not modify frame) on `viewDidLoad`, at this moment, the view have not been layout and result in wrong frame, instead, move it to `viewDidLayoutSubView` or `viewWillAppear`

Second, if the view is already created in storyboard with constraint, just drag the constraint as property and change it then call `layoutIfNeeded`, don't change the frame